# Extracting and plotting data from a MultiIndex DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I've managed to get the following table into a pandas DataFrame. It has a multi-dimensional index (file_type, server_count, file_count, thread_count, cacheclear_type) which represents a configuration for some performance measurement. I then have 5 runs for each configuration.

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|           |              |            |              |                 | run_001 | run_002 | run_003 | run_004 | run_005 |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| file_type | server_count | file_count | thread_count | cacheclear_type |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| gor       | 01servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 15.918  | 16.275  | 15.807  | 17.781  | 16.233  |
|           | 08servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 17.061  | 15.414  | 16.819  | 15.597  | 16.818  |
| gorz      | 01servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 12.285  | 11.218  | 12.009  | 14.122  | 10.991  |
|           | 08servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 9.881   | 9.405   | 9.322   | 10.184  | 9.924   |
| gor       | 01servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 17.322  | 17.636  | 16.096  | 16.484  | 16.715  |
|           | 08servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 17.167  | 17.666  | 15.950  | 18.867  | 16.569  |
| gorz      | 01servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 14.718  | 19.553  | 17.930  | 21.415  | 21.495  |
|           | 08servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 10.236  | 9.948   | 12.605  | 9.780   | 10.320  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 19.265  | 17.128  | 17.630  | 18.739  | 16.833  |
|           | 08servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 23.083  | 22.084  | 25.024  | 24.677  | 20.648  |
| gorz      | 01servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 15.401  | 28.282  | 28.727  | 24.645  | 27.509  |
|           | 08servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 10.307  | 12.217  | 13.005  | 12.277  | 12.224  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 23.744  | 20.539  | 21.416  | 22.921  | 22.794  |
|           | 08servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 35.393  | 36.218  | 35.949  | 35.157  | 37.342  |
| gorz      | 01servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 19.505  | 23.756  | 25.767  | 26.575  | 25.239  |
|           | 08servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 11.398  | 11.332  | 15.086  | 16.115  | 13.479  |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to take all the gor,1servers,20threads,ccALWAYS configurations and create one data point for each of the XXfiles configurations. So to begin with I'd like to somehow get a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|           |              |            |              |                 | run_001 | run_002 | run_003 | run_004 | run_005 |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| file_type | server_count | file_count | thread_count | cacheclear_type |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| gor       | 01servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 15.918  | 16.275  | 15.807  | 17.781  | 16.233  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 17.322  | 17.636  | 16.096  | 16.484  | 16.715  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 19.265  | 17.128  | 17.630  | 18.739  | 16.833  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 23.744  | 20.539  | 21.416  | 22.921  | 22.794  |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Well I finally figured out how to filter the dataframe using the query function:

    df.query('file_type == "gor" & server_count == "08servers"').sortlevel(2)

Comment: Since nothing is coming of this I'm going to edit the question to focus it on how to do the data filtering only. I've added another question about the plotting only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380957/plotting-a-line-plot-with-error-bars-and-datapoints-from-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I managed to filter the data using the query() function to get it to look like the second table in the question using the following code:

```
df.query('file_type == "gor" & server_count == "01servers"').sortlevel(2)
```