# Plotting a line plot with error bars and datapoints from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot

I've been racking my brain to try to figure out how to plot a pandas DataFrame the way I want but to no avail.

The DataFrame has a MultiIndex and it looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|           |              |            |              |                 | run_001 | run_002 | run_003 | run_004 | run_005 |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| file_type | server_count | file_count | thread_count | cacheclear_type |         |         |         |         |         |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| gor       | 01servers    | 05files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 15.918  | 16.275  | 15.807  | 17.781  | 16.233  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 10files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 17.322  | 17.636  | 16.096  | 16.484  | 16.715  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 15files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 19.265  | 17.128  | 17.630  | 18.739  | 16.833  |
| gor       | 01servers    | 20files    | 20threads    | ccALWAYS        | 23.744  | 20.539  | 21.416  | 22.921  | 22.794  |
+-----------+--------------+------------+--------------+-----------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

What I want to do is plot a line graph where the x values are the 'file_count' value, and the y value for each is the average of all the run_xxx values for the corresponding line in the DataFrame.

If possible I would like to add error bars and even the data points themselves so that I can see the distribution of the data behind that average.

Here's a (crappy) mockup of roughly what I'm talking about:

[image: mockup of desired graph]

I've been able to create a boxplot using the boxplot() function built into pandas' DataFrame by doing:

```
df.transpose().boxplot()
```

This looks almost okay but a little bit cluttered and doesn't have the actual data points plotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Beeswarm](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mgymrek/pybeeswarm/blob/master/beeswarm_example.ipynb) plot will very nice in this situation, especially when you have a lot of dots and what to show the distributions of those dots. You need to, however, supply the `position` parameter to `beeswarm` as by default it will started at 0. The the `boxplot` method of `pandas` `DataFrame`, on the other hand, plots boxes at x = 1, 2 ...

It comes down to just these:

```
from beeswarm import *
D1 = beeswarm(df.values, positions = np.arange(len(df.values))+1)
D2 = df.transpose().boxplot(ax=D1[1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps although I did manage to claw my way out of this today. I'll accept your answer though as it does answer my question and I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'll include the way I finally managed to do this here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

dft = df.sortlevel(2).transpose()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = []
y = []
y_err = []

scatterx = []
scattery = []

for n, col in enumerate(dft.columns):
    x.append(n)
    y.append(np.mean(dft[col]))
    y_err.append(np.std(dft[col]))

    for v in dft[col]:
        scattery.append(v)
        scatterx.append(n + ((random.random()-0.5)*0.05))

p = plt.plot(x, y, label=label)
color=p[0].get_color()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=y_err, fmt=color)
plt.scatter(scatterx, scattery, alpha=0.3, color=color)

plt.legend(loc=2)
ax.set_xticks(range(len(dft.columns)))
ax.set_xticklabels([x[2] for x in dft.columns])
plt.show()
```

This will show a line chart with error bars and data points. There may be some errors in the above code. I copied it and simplified a bit before pasting here.